# recursive matching for string delimiter with regular expression

Tags: regex, recursion

In verilog language, the statements are enclosed in a begin-end delimiter instead of bracket.

```
always@ (*) begin
    if (condA) begin
       a = c
    end
    else begin
       b = d
    end
end
```

I'd like to parse outermost begin-end with its statements to check coding rule in python. Using regular expression, I want results with regular expression like:

```
if (condA) begin
   a = c
end
else begin
   b = d
end
```

I found similar answer for bracket delimiter.

```
int funcA() {
  if (condA) {
    b = a
  }
}
```

regular expression:

```
/({(?>[^{}]+|(?R))*})/g
```

However, I don't know how to modify atomic group **([^{}])** for "begin-end"?

```
/(begin(?>[??????]+|(?R))*end)/g
```

Comment: `*` is a greedy quantifier. It will find the longest matching sequence. Maybe I misunderstand something, but I think this may work: `begin([\s\S]*)end` Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kh5JqN/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the `[??????]+` part is to match any text that does not match a char that is equal or is the starting point of the delimiters.

So, in your case, you need to match any char other than a char that starts either `begin` or `end` substring:

```
/begin(?>(?!begin|end).|(?R))*end/gs
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RwnlN/2)

The `.` here will match any char including line break chars due to the `s` modifier. Note that the actual implementation might need adjustments (e.g. in PHP, the `g` modifier should not be used as there are specific functions/features for that).

Also, since you recurse the whole pattern, you need no outer parentheses.

Comment: Unrolling the pattern may yield better performance, but it becomes too cryptic and unwieldly, see [`begin(?:[^be]*(?:(?:b(?!egin)|e(?!nd))[^be]*)*|(?R))*end`](https://regex101.com/r/1RwnlN/3).